# Graphics.RenderTexture() causes extra image to appear on canavas

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have some code like this:

```
readonly Rect WORK_SOURCE_RECT = new Rect(0f, 0f, 1f, 1f);
Color[] workPixels;

void Start() {
  Texture2D workTexture = new Texture2D(256, 256, GraphicsFormat.R8G8B8A8_UNorm, 
    TextureCreationFlags.None);
  workPixels = workTexture.GetPixels();
}

void OnGUI() {
  workTexture.SetPixels(workPixels);
  workTexture.Apply();
  Graphics.DrawTexture(toRect, workTexture, WORK_SOURCE_RECT, 
                0, 0, 0, 0, renderColor);
}

void Update() {
  // Omitted - Some changes are made by code here to the workPixels array.
}
```

The call to Graphics.DrawTexture() correctly draws the content of workTexture to the screen, just how I want it. But there is a strange side effect...

Any other GUI that is drawn inside of a scene object containing a Canvas component, will show an extra Y-reversed copy of the work texture. (Nevermind the reversal--not the issue.) I don't know why this extra image is drawn. It seems like there is a shared resource between two GUI things I'd hoped were completely unrelated.

In the image shown below, the reversed-face on the right is the unwanted extra render. Strangely it appears when I move to the right side of my scene, so it's like it is in world space. But it will update when GUI-based elements like subtitles are shown.

On Unity 2019.4.13f1 with MacOS.

[image]

Comment: `If you want to draw a texture from inside of OnGUI code, you should only do that from EventType.Repaint events.` have you tried that? In general the `OnGUI` is quite legacy .. why not use a simple `Image` or `RawImage` component?

Comment: Thanks for pointing me towards EventType.Repaint. I'll look into it. With some very good luck, I did actually find a solution which I will repost below.

Comment: So many times on SO I post something, spend about 30 minutes trying to get the question clear and generally useful to others, and someone mods it down with no explanation. To that person I say, you're not being helpful. What am I to learn from you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I found that resolved my problem was camera stacking. I created a second camera that was culled to just UI layer. The first camera had UI layer removed from culling. And then the calls to Graphics.DrawTexture() no longer appeared on the canvas used for UI.